# Trying to work out these interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create some interfaces. The `IReportSection` object will have one string and a collection of items, which could be different depending on what we're working with. Do I need to make it generic?

The `IReport` will have one string and a collection of `IReportSection`.

Here's how I'm trying to define it now.

```
public interface IReport
{
    string ReportName { get; set; }

    ICollection<IReportSection> ReportSections { get; }
}

public interface IReportSection
{
    string ReportSectionName { get; set; }

    ICollection ReportItems { get; }
}

public abstract class ReportSectionBase : IReportSection
{
    public string ReportSectionName { get; set; }

    public ICollection ReportItems { get; set; }
}
```

And my models:

```
pulic class ProjectSubmissionViewModel
{
    public int ProjectSubmissionId { get; set; }
    public string SubmissionTitle { get; set; }
}

pulic class AffiliateViewModel
{
    public int AffiliateId { get; set; }
    public string AffiliateName { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to use it in code:

```
public class ChapterAffiliates : ReportSectionBase
{
    public string ReportSectionName { get { return "Chapter Affiliates"; } }

    public ICollection<AffiliateViewModel> ReportItems { get; set; }
}

public class ChapterTitles : ReportSectionBase
{
    public string ReportSectionName { get { return "Chapter Titles"; } }

    public ICollection<ProjectSubmissionViewModel> ReportItems { get; set; }
}

public class SubmissionListViewModel : IReport
{
    public ICollection<ProjectSubmissionViewModel> Submissions { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AffiliateViewModel> Affiliates{ get; set; }

    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IReportSection> ReportSections
    {
        get
        {
            var affiliateSection = new ChapterAffiliates
            {
                ReportItems = Affiliates
            };

            var titleSection = new ChapterTitles 
            {
                ReportItems = Submissions.Where(s => s.SubmissionTitle.Contains("SomePhrase")).ToList()
            };

            var sections = new List<IReportSection> { {subSection}, {titleSection} };

            return sections; 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to best define this. I'm pretty sure I've done it before, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: `IReport` needs a generic parameter `T`: `public interface IReport<T>`.

Comment: public interface IReport<T>

Comment: just wondering if you making it generic why are you calling it report items? wouldnt that imply it's always a report

Comment: I adjusted my description and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the type parameters for `TRType` all the same within a certain report? E.g. will you have report sections with different report types in them?

If all types within a report are the same, the solution is relatively simple:

```
public interface IReport<T> { ... }
```

If this is not the case - you'll have to do something different, e.g:

```
public interface IReportSection
{
    string ReportSectionName { get; }

    ICollection ReportItems { get; }
}

public abstract class ReportSectionBase<TRType> : IReportSection {
   ...
}
```

This allows you to put different underlying types in the `ReportSections` collection related to the report. You'll have to do some more work to get the exact information that you need out of each report section.

Comment: Updated my code. Trying to explain better what I'm trying to get.